# How to use bash(3.2.25)'s An additional binary operator：=~

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I feel confused about how to use "=~" when I read the info of bash(3.2.25) at rhel5.5

```
# match the IP, and return true
[kevin@server1 shell]# [[ 192.168.1.1 =~ "^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$" ]] && echo ok || echo fail
ok
```

```
# add double qoute
# return false, en ... I know.
[kevin@server1 shell]# [[ 192.168 =~ "^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$" ]] && echo ok || echo fail
fail

# remove double qoute
# return ture ? Why ?
[kevin@server1 shell]# [[ 192.168 =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]] && echo ok || echo fail
ok
```

So, should I qoute the string to the right of the operator ?
**And why the second command return true，apparently it should return false !**

Here is what the info said:

> An additional binary operator, `=~', is available, with the same
>   precedence as`==' and `!='.  When it is used, the string to the
>   right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression
>   and matched accordingly (as in regex3)).  The return value is 0 if
>   the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.  If the regular
>   expression is syntactically incorrect, the conditional
>   expression's return value is 2.  If the shell option`nocasematch'
>   (see the description of `shopt' in *Note Bash Builtins::) is
>   enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of
>   alphabetic characters.  Substrings matched by parenthesized
>   subexpressions within the regular expression are saved in the
>   array variable`BASH_REMATCH'.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH' with
>   index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular
>   expression.  The element of`BASH_REMATCH' with index N is the
>   portion of the string matching the Nth parenthesized subexpression.

Comment: The first example will only work in RHEL 5. This is a "bug" that was fixed in bash but RHEL kept it in for backwards compatibility reasons. In all other versions the quoted string is treated as literal, not as regex. I can't reproduce any of your results in bash 4.1.

Comment: @jordanm
I know it that in bash4.2, qoute will treate string as literal, unqoute will treate string as regex.
But why the second command return ture ？

Comment: My guess: without the quotes, the regex undergoes quote removal *before*  being used as a regex, which means the periods are no longer quoted and the regex engine sees them as the wild-card character.

Comment: Yes, it is! And now I know why the second command return ture, because shell re-parse the regex to ^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$，so, it means "0-9 number, any char, 0-9 number, any char, 0-9 number, any char, 0-9 number", and match 192.168

Answer (score 1):

The recommended, most widely compatible way of dealing with regular expression patterns is to declare them separately, in single quotes:

```
$ re='^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'
$ [[ 192.168.1.1 =~ $re ]] && echo ok || echo fail 
ok
$ [[ 192.168 =~ $re ]] && echo ok || echo fail 
fail
```

Some discussion on the differences in behaviour across bash versions can be found on [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions) - the take-home message is that using an unquoted variable is the best way to do it.

Comment: You are right! But why the second command return ture ? can you example it ? does it a 'BUG' ?

Comment: @lxf1992521 the second one only has 2 octets, but the regex requires 4 octets, so it does not match, thus it fails

Comment: @Eric Renouf 
oh, sorry. the second example is my question's second example.
But in  my question's second example , It return True!

Comment: It may be possible that since you are not putting the regex as a string, and therefore the regex is not considered as a literal, you may be getting a parcial match that will return true. Maybe?

Comment: @lxf1992521 I'm afraid I can't answer your question of _why_ it behaves like that in your version of bash. All I can suggest is that you use the approach I have mentioned, which should work as expected.

Comment: I don't konw.  when ever treate the ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ as string or  regex, it all should return false!!! But in my question's second example , It return True!!! that's what I concerned

Answer (score 0):

Not relevant to the operator itself, however, your regular expression is not limiting each byte of the IP address being matched to be between 0-255. That regex will accept IP's such as: 999.999.999.999.

Please do consider using the following:

> ^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$

This will match between 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255. I use this is regex in java but i do believe the syntax to be the same. If not please do tell.

Comment: Thanks, your example is perfect!  But what I want to know is why the second command return ture?